# Problem in recognizing some classes in bootstrap for PDF conversion in ASP.NET MVC using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, bootstrap-4, html-to-pdf

I have an Html string generated by Bootstrap, I want to convert this text to PDF using the `HtmlToPdfConverter` library, but the problem is that it doesn't recognize all the cols and lowers the cols and the PDF file It does not create HTML as an image.

Html markup:

```
<html>
<head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF8">
    <link href='***/font.css' rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href='*****/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='****/main.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='****/main-light-color.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
    <link href='****/css-controller.css' rel='stylesheet'/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="page-wrapper">
      <div class="main-container">
        <div class="row gutters justify-content-center font15">
          <div style="text-align: center;">
            <strong>BaseTitre</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gutters justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="row gutters">
                <div class="list-group-item justify-content-between col-3">
                  <span class="font12 IranSansBold t-pink">Sample 0</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item justify-content-between col-3"> Sample1: <span class="font12 IranSansBold">***** </div>
                <div class="list-group-item justify-content-between col-3"> Sample2: <span class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item justify-content-between col-3"> Sample3: <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gutters justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table custom-table m-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #229954;" class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-white">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>***</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table custom-table m-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #e74c3c;" class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-white">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table custom-table m-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="background-color: #884ea0;" class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-white">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-black-50">****</td>
                    <td class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-black-50">****</td>
                    <td class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-black-50">****</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>******</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">*****</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-3">
            <div class="table-responsive">
              <table class="table custom-table m-0">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" style="background-color: #2e86c1;" class="text-center IranSansBold font12 text-white">***</td>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">***</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">***</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>*****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">***</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>******</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">***</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>****</td>
                    <td class="font12 IranSansBold">***</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row gutters justify-content-center mt-2">
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="bg-dark text-center p-2 text-white">*****</div>
              <div class="row gutters mx-1">
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> ***** : <span class="font12 IranSans badge badge-success">****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> **** : <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> **** <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> **** : <span class="font12 IranSansBold">***</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> **** : <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> **** <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
                <div class="list-group-item text-dark justify-content-between col-4"> *** <span class="font12 IranSansBold">****</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

C# for converting Html to PDF:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("GeneratedHtmlToPdf")]
[NoCache]
public HttpResponseMessage GeneratedHtmlToPdf(GeneratedHtmlToPdfRequest request)
{
            try
            {
                var pdf = new HtmlToPdfConverter()
                {
                    Orientation = PageOrientation.Landscape,
                    Size = PageSize.A4,
                    LowQuality = false
                };

                var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Content = new StreamContent(new MemoryStream(pdf.GeneratePdf(request.Html)))
                };

                response.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
                return response;
            }
            catch
            {
                return null;
            }
 }
```

HTML screenshot:

[image]

But the final file looks like this:

[image]

Comment: To my knowledge the HtmlToPdfConverter is not able recognize the Bootstrap stylesheets or any external stylesheets in the ``<head>`` of the html document. You will need to write the styles manually.

Comment: It recognizes some items, it does not recognize some items. If you see in the picture, the color of the texts has changed with the `t-pink` class. @Örvar

Comment: There is no "t-pink" in the official Bootstrap documentation. You can try to change the way the path to the external stylesheet is constructed to see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: @Örvar All the files are located in the same path, and it also detects the `col`, but the problem is that it does not put the `div`s together